# The fastest way in Python to merge and remove duplicate ids

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, numpy

I have two different querysets I need to merge together then remove any duplicate ids. There is over a over a million records.

```
list_a = Wharehouse.orders.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
list_b = Shops.orders.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Is there a fast pythonic way of doing this?

I can think of using a list comprehension and looping each value. But, could this be done in numpy better/faster or maybe a set? The output only needs to be a list of ids.

I'm using Python 3.4 and Django with numpy 1.11.0 pip installed.

Comment: Try to use both approaches and time them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `list_a`, and `list_b` are lists of integers, you could use `np.union1d(list_a, list_b)`. Using:

```
import numpy as np
N = 10**6
list_a = np.random.randint(2*10**6, size=N).tolist()
list_b = np.random.randint(2*10**6, size=N).tolist()
```

---

Here is a benchmark suggesting [`np.union1d`](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) may be faster when applied to lists with around a million elements:

```
In [32]: %timeit np.union1d(list_a, list_b)
1 loop, best of 3: 296 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit set(list_a + list_b)
1 loop, best of 3: 308 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit set(list_a).union(list_b)
1 loop, best of 3: 338 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit list(set(list_a + list_b))
1 loop, best of 3: 382 ms per loop
```

Note, of course, that `np.union1d` returns a NumPy array, while `set` and `list` return Python objects of the eponymous type so the benchmark is to some extent an apples-to-orange comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it to a `set` to remove the duplicates. You can then return it to a list. To concatenate the lists use the `+` operator. It will do just this (at least with normal lists)

```
merged = list(set(list_a + list_b))
```

Comment: Thank you Vogon Jeltz, a set is a good idea, but would numpy be faster?

Comment: Note that `ValuesListQuerySet` don't support addition. You should convert them to lists or some other data-structure first.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary does`` flat=True`` not make it a simple list?

Comment: It might be a bit faster, but the operation on my computer takes upto 20ms on my computer with lists of 10,000 elements

Comment: @Spaceships Nop, it is still a queryset.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`Sets`.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sets#set)

We create 2 sets `set_a` and `set_b`. `set_a` contains all the ids of `Wharehouse` objects. `set_b` contains all the `Shops` ids. Now to get all unique ids combined, we use `union` operation on sets.  `final_set` contains all the desired unique ids.

```
set_a = set(Wharehouse.orders.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
set_b = set(Shops.orders.all().values_list('id', flat=True))

final_set = set_a.union(set_b) # contains all unique ids combined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shops_query=Shops.orders.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
result = Wharehouse.orders.all().exclude(id__in=shops_query).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Let the DB do the work.

Comment: But you still need one operation to get the actual union i.e `result` is not the actual result here. Plus depending on the DB using another queryset in `__in` can actually turn out to be slow. You should convert the results of `shops_query` to a `list()` first before passing it to the next query to reduce it to a single query for `shops_query`'s IDs.